How to connect to a local PostgreSQL database to follow the "Learn Next.js" tutorial?
I am trying to follow the 'Learn Next.js' guide and I am on the database setup chapter: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/setting-up-your-database
I am trying to use the guide with a local PostgreSQL and not Vercel.
I installed PostgreSQL and I have a user called postgres with password password and this is how I setup my env file:
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DATABASE=learn_nextjs

I am new to both Next.js and PostgreSQL, so in order to try to connect to the DB, I followed another guide, and installed the pg npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg
I then created a db.js file:
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const db = new Pool({
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE    
});


export default db;

And instead of importing db from @vercel/postgres I imported it from /database/db'.
But I get Error 500: TypeError: client.sql is not a function. My db.js file does not contain the connect() method as seen below in the seeding file: const client = await db.connect();.
How can I update the db.js so that it will contain the correct connect() method?
This is how the file that should create the tables look like:
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
// import { db } from '@vercel/postgres';
import db from 'database/db';
import { invoices, customers, revenue, users } from '../lib/placeholder-data';

const client = await db.connect();

async function seedUsers() {
  await client.sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;
  await client.sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
      id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      password TEXT NOT NULL
    );
  `;

  const insertedUsers = await Promise.all(
    users.map(async (user) => {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
      return client.sql`
        INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password)
        VALUES (${user.id}, ${user.name}, ${user.email}, ${hashedPassword})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `;
    }),
  );

  return insertedUsers;
}

async function seedInvoices() {
  await client.sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;

  await client.sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoices (
      id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
      customer_id UUID NOT NULL,
      amount INT NOT NULL,
      status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      date DATE NOT NULL
    );
  `;

  const insertedInvoices = await Promise.all(
    invoices.map(
      (invoice) => client.sql`
        INSERT INTO invoices (customer_id, amount, status, date)
        VALUES (${invoice.customer_id}, ${invoice.amount}, ${invoice.status}, ${invoice.date})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `,
    ),
  );

  return insertedInvoices;
}

async function seedCustomers() {
  await client.sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;

  await client.sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
      id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
  `;

  const insertedCustomers = await Promise.all(
    customers.map(
      (customer) => client.sql`
        INSERT INTO customers (id, name, email, image_url)
        VALUES (${customer.id}, ${customer.name}, ${customer.email}, ${customer.image_url})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `,
    ),
  );

  return insertedCustomers;
}

async function seedRevenue() {
  await client.sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS revenue (
      month VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      revenue INT NOT NULL
    );
  `;

  const insertedRevenue = await Promise.all(
    revenue.map(
      (rev) => client.sql`
        INSERT INTO revenue (month, revenue)
        VALUES (${rev.month}, ${rev.revenue})
        ON CONFLICT (month) DO NOTHING;
      `,
    ),
  );

  return insertedRevenue;
}

export async function GET() {
  // return Response.json({
  //   message:
  //     'Uncomment this file and remove this line. You can delete this file when you are finished.',
  // });
  try {
    await client.sql`BEGIN`;
    await seedUsers();
    await seedCustomers();
    await seedInvoices();
    await seedRevenue();
    await client.sql`COMMIT`;

    return Response.json({ message: 'Database seeded successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    await client.sql`ROLLBACK`;
    return Response.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

I guess the db I am importing is way off the one I needed to create and I am missing some code there in the db.js file, but I am not sure what to do.

"But I get Error 500." - All that indicates is that an error occurred, but it gives no information about that error.  Is there anything useful in the response body or headers about the error?  Anything in the console in the browser or on the server?

Hi sorry I updated the post as well, the error is: TypeError: client.sql is not a function, and since the db.js file I created doesn't have such method I clearly have missing code there. (The line on the seeding file is const client = await db.connect();)

The documentation for the pg package leads me here, in which it appears that the function you're looking for is called query, not sql.  If you've changed the database library from what's in the tutorial then you'll need to reference the documentation for the library you're using, not what's in the tutorial.  (There's an argument to be made on SO as to whether this qualifies as a kind of typo, when one is simply following the wrong product documentation.)

Thank you! Now I get: A query must have either text or a name. Supplying neither is unsupported.. I will keep looking in the link to the docs you sent. But maybe you already know the solution?

Not off-hand, unfortunately.  I'd be doing the same Googling that you are.  Glad you got some progress though!
